# Generic Reporting system using Java, Hibernate, MySQL

Tags: java, hibernate, dynamic, reporting

I have a requirement where-in I need to provide the client with an option to define and design his own set of reports, kind of do it yourself. The user needs to be provided with the option to select the required entities, and its attributes, define the sort condition, grouping mode, options for charts etc.

Is there any open-source systems in java which can do something like that? I have checked JasperReports, DynamicJasper and Pentaho reporting systems. But they dont fit into the way as my client needs. He is kind of novice when it comes to setting up SQL. So i basically need a simpler but effective way to proceed on this. The database is setup in MySQL (InnoDB). Tables are already related, but the issue is that user does not know how the tables have been mapped. So he is at the disposal to select any table and generate a report on that. Need some ways to do that.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look at Eclipse BIRT: http://eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

Comment: if you dont know how the tables are mapped, God help you! how would you create hibernate mappings then? Jasper's pretty good, i would say re look at it :-) good luck!

Comment: Hi, Well as a developer we know the relationships. It is the end-user who will not be aware of it. We need to know how to expose the same to the end-user so that he can make use of a generic reporting module. We have already defined the relationships and it is working quite fine. There are few tables which are nested deeply and such structures needs to be properly exposed to end user for the correct mapping to make sure the data is correctly fetched.